# Can I add tables or fields to access back end file while others are using the front end?

Tags: sql, sql-server, ms-access, vba

A similar question was asked previously but does not answer my question. I have a split database with back end and front end in Access. I have 10 users. I wish to append data to existing tables or add new fields while users are using the front end. I see in a previous thread that it is not recommended to edit a live back end.

Is there a way with VBA and SQL to add fields or append data to the back end through the front end without the risk of corrupting the database?

Also if I moved the back end to SQL Server, would I be able to add data or edit data in the back end while the front end is in use?

Comment: I don't know enough about Access, but the answer to your last question is yes: SQL Server is an, ahem, proper database system, and those all support concurrent modifications and querying. SQL Server will do so by taking appropriate locks, so there can still be a need to schedule downtime if tables are in continuous use and you need to change the table structure, but barring hardware failure or a severe bug, the database will never corrupt. It's one of the big selling points of "professional" databases.

Answer (score 1):

You can quite well do this with SQL server. If you add new columns, then again now problem. Note that the FE will not see new tables or new columns until you re-link the front end. In effect it quite safe to do this.

Answer (score 0):

We can do but it is not recommended.IF there are any dependencies on the table that script/procedures would be failing.

Create procedure using dynamic SQL and call this procedure in front-end code based on the requirement

```
Create procedure Name2
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max)
SET @SQL ='ALTER Table Temp
   ADD  Name INT '

EXEC(@SQL)

END

EXEC Name2
```

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the other answers given - you can add new tables or new data to the sql backend of an access frontend that is in use.  Adding new fields to active tables would be the most risky. All of these actions should be absolutely fine, but there is always the possibility of dependencies or some other circumstance that causes a corruption.  So the best answer is, you need to assess your particular situation.  Is the access system critical to your 10 users?  So if your work on the backend does cause a corruption, will they be ok without for a short time while you restore it from backup?  If you have to restore to a backup, can they easily recreate the work that they have lost? If yes to both of those, you can do the work while they are using it, but if not then you need to do it when the front end isn't in use.  Secondly, before you do any work on the backend always remember to check that the most recent backup is a) actually recent and b) does restore as expected.